# LINQ Query to check for a predicate in all columns in a table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table with 30 columns,
and it contains 1000 rows.
I want a single LINQ query,  which checks for a particular value in all columns and converts the result into a list.

For example:

```
table.where(allcolumnvalue.contains(searchvalue)).Tolist()
```

How to accomplish the above using one LINQ query. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds as if you have forgotten to normalize your table, because you have to search a value across different columns it seems those are related so you should store them in another n-m table

Comment: Please Explain sample Answer

Answer (score 2):

For your request all of fields should have same type, at least in the static typed C#.

The method `Queriable.Where` gets the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` predicate as parameter. So you need build the predicate `o.p1 == val || o.p2 == val || o.p3 = val ...` as `Expression` value. Here `o` is a parameter of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`:

```
public Expression BuildExpression<TObj, TVal>(TObj obj, TVal val)
{
    Expression<Func<TObj, bool>> predicate = (o) => o.p1 == val || ... || o.pN == val;
    return predicate;
}
```

but we need build predicate dynamically for all properties of `TObj` that have type `TVal`.

To simplify the code we will build equal expression `false || o.p1 == val || ... || o.pN == val`.

```
public Expression<Func<TObj, bool>> BuildExpression<TObj, TVal>(TVal val)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObj), "o");
    var valExpression = Expression.Constant(val, typeof(TVal));
    var body = Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool));

    var properties = typeof(TObj).GetProperties()
                                 .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TVal));
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        var equalExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, valExpression);
        body = Expression.Or(body, equalExpression);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TObj, bool>>(body, parameter);
}

. . .

using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    var whereExpression = BuildExpression<User, string>("foo");
    var contaningsFoo = dbContext.Users.Where(whereExpression);
}
```

Comment: In the statement body = Expression.Or(result, equalExpression) what does result represent?  It is not defined elsewhere in the method

Comment: @Alex First, `body` stores the `false` value, then it stores `false || o.p1 == val`, then `false || o.p1 == val || o.p2 == val`, and so on.

Comment: But what is 'result'?  I don't see that defined anywhere in the method..  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Alex. Oh, I see. Sorry, my mistake. Should be `body = Expression.Or(body, equalExpression)`. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer But Is not perfect answer  But Is Worked well

```
   public class GenericList<T>
{
    void Add(T input) { }

    public List<T> SerachFun(List<T> input, string search)
    {
        List<T> output = new System.Collections.Generic.List<T>();
        foreach (var aa in input)
        {
            var columns = aa.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
            foreach (var bb in columns)
            {
                var cccc = bb.GetValue(aa);
                bool result = cccc.ToString().Contains(search);
                if (result)
                {
                    output.Add(aa);
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

The Generic Class Object Created

```
        public GenericList<table1> g = new GenericList<table1>();
```

the Generic Class Method Called :

```
   var tabledetails=db.table1.ToList();
   var resultcommonsearch = g.SerachFun(tabledetails, "Dhoni");
```

Answer (score 0):

using code

```
public class GenericList<T>
{
     public List<T> SerachFun(List<T> input, string search)
     {
            List<T> output = new System.Collections.Generic.List<T>();
            foreach (var aa in input)
            {
               var columns = aa.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
               foreach (var bb in columns)
               {
                  var cccc = bb.GetValue(aa);
                  if(cccc!=null)
                  {
                     bool result = cccc.ToString().Contains(search);
                     if (result)
                     {
                        output.Add(aa);
                        continue;
                      }
                  }

              }

         }
            return output;
    }
  }
```

Try call method

```
 public GenericList<table1> g = new GenericList<table1>();

 var tabledetails=db.table1.ToList();
 var resultcommonsearch = g.SerachFun(tabledetails, "Dhoni");
```